# Domain Controller 2019 Event ID 1074, Reason Code: 0x50006 Lsass.exe terminated unexpectedly

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

The process wininit.exe has initiated the restart of computer Domain Controller 2019 on behalf of user for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
Reason Code: 0x50006
Shutdown Type: restart
Comment: The system process 'C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe' terminated unexpectedly with status code -1073740767. The system will now shut down and restart.

Faulting application name: lsass.exe, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0xf1beaffa
Faulting module name: verifier.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0x197d3cfd
Exception code: 0xc0000421
Fault offset: 0x0000000000006646
Faulting process id: 0x2a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d77174ea850ebe
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\verifier.dll
Report Id: 62e62818-ccba-40c1-a815-e036fe1c42c9
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

I detected that when I stop NETLOGON Services, server 2019 doesn't restart unexpectedly. But when start NETLOGON Services, it still restart every 5 ~ 10 minutes.

Comment: Can you provide the output of these commands please:
`verifier /query` and `verifier /querysettings`